# .not(this) not working?

Tags: jquery

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/watson/tnXxF/3/)

I've got this basic accordion which toggles a class of 'block'. Everything is working, except
the `.not(this)` in `$('.accordionInner').not(this).removeClass('block');` is not working, so you can never close all the accordions. I am sure it is a simple fix, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

HTML:

```
<div class="accordionHeading">
    <p>Header</p>
</div>
<div class="accordionInner">
    <p>Inner</p>
</div>
<div class="accordionHeading">
    <p>Header</p>
</div>
<div class="accordionInner">
    <p>Inner</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.accordionHeading {
    cursor: pointer;
    background: yellow;
}
.accordionInner {
    display: none;
}
.block {
    display: block !important;
}
```

JS:

```
 $('body').on('click', '.accordionHeading', function(){
  $('.accordionInner').not(this).removeClass('block');
  $(this).next('.accordionInner').toggleClass('block');
 });
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The event is on the heading, so `this` will never be any of the "inner" elements.

Use the reference that you get using `next` in the `not` also:

```
$('body').on('click', '.accordionHeading', function(){
  var inner = $(this).next('.accordionInner');
  $('.accordionInner').not(inner).removeClass('block');
  inner.toggleClass('block');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Updated your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tnXxF/4/

The problem was here:

```
$('.accordionInner').not(this).removeClass('block');
```

You are selecting accordionInner, but the click event was on accordionHeading, so .not(this) could never work.

Solution in fiddle:

```
$('body').on('click', '.accordionHeading', function(){
  var targetInner = $(this).next('.accordionInner');
  $('.accordionInner').not(targetInner).removeClass('block');
  targetInner.toggleClass('block');
});
```

Edit:
As mentioned in the comments, targetInner does not need to be wrapped in a jquery object again.

Comment: `targetInner` is a jQuery object, so you don't need to do `$(targetInner)`.

Answer (score 0):

Since your `.accordionHeading` and `.accordionInner` elements are siblings (not parent:child) you shouldn't need to use the `this` on your header's click events.

Your Javascript is mostly correct, just change it to:

```
$('body').on('click', '.accordionHeading', function(){
  $(this).next('.accordionInner').toggleClass('block');
});
```

So now when an `accordionHeading` is clicked it will find the next occurance of an `accordionInner` and toggle the `block` class to trigger expansion or contraction.

Optionally you could also use the jQuery [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) method to do the show/hide for you without a custom class.